# Strategy pattern to read different file formats

Tags: java, strategy-pattern

```
public interface FileReader {

  void readFile();
   void writeFile();
}


 public class XMLReader implements FileReader {

  @Override
   public void readFile() {
    System.out.println("Hellp i am read");

   }

   @Override
   public void writeFile() {
        System.out.println("Hello i am write");
    }


 }

  public class ExcelReader implements FileReader {

  @Override
   public void readFile() {
    System.out.println("Hellp i am read");

   }

   @Override
   public void writeFile() {
        System.out.println("Hello i am write");
    }

}

public class Context {

   FileReader reader ;

   public Context(FileReader reader) {
    super();
    this.reader = reader;
   }

   public void executeRead(){

        reader.readFile();
    }


       }

public class TestStrategy {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println(args[0]);
    String s=args[0];
    String[] a=s.split("\\.");
    if(a[1].equals("csv")){
        new Context(new XMLReader()).executeRead();
    }else{
        new Context(new ExcelReader()).executeRead();
    }
}

}
```

I have a concern more file format are introduced we will create separate class for them but i have to change the if else code in TestStrategy class to create new object for the file pattern introduced.

Can we remove this if else code .Any suggestions.

Comment: Are you familiar with the factory pattern?

Comment: you can use and abstract class that will do something like `if (test == ok) readFile` then each of your classes will inherit this behavior. and now your stategy will have to loop through every classes that inherit the abtract class. and each strategy will encapsulate her own condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a registry that maps a files extension to the implementation.

```
public class Registry {
    static Map<String,FileReader> reg = new HashMap<String,FileReader>();

    public static void register(String ext, FileReader fr ) {
        reg.put( ext, fr );
    }
}
```

and let newly added implementation register themself e.g.

```
public class XMLReader implements FileReader {
        static {
            Registry.register( "xml", new XMLReader() );
        }
....
public class ExcelReader implements FileReader {
        static {
            Registry.register( "xls", new ExcelReader() );
        }
...
```

then you could simply lookup the registry for a suitable implementation with no *if* or *switch* required.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a class by name. Build a `Map` to configure the `FileReader` to use for each extension.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
  throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, String> extensionToClass = new HashMap<>();
    extensionToClass.put("xml", "de.lhorn.XMLReader");
    extensionToClass.put("xls", "de.lhorn.ExcelReader");

    String s = "foo.xml";
    String[] a = s.split("\\.");
    String extension = a[1];

    // Get the class that is configured for the extension.
    String className = extensionToClass.get(extension);
    Class clazz = Class.forName(className);

    // Create a new instance of this class.
    FileReader reader = (FileReader) clazz.newInstance();

    // Use the FileReader.
    new Context(reader).executeRead();
}
```

You can read `extensionToClass` from an external source, of course.